# mariaDB (MySQL) Still Gets Error 1415 for "Not allowed to return a result set from a function" after using SELECT INTO

Tags: mysql, sql, function, mariadb, procedure

Sorry for yet another question about the MySQL error 1415 again!

But I have spent two hours on this - I have read - I think - all of the similar questions regarding to error 1415 on StackOverflow, as well as many results from Google, but unfortunately, I still could not find out where I got wrong with the following function declaration.

I am using the standard **1GB** *TPC-H* database to do some course assignments. And this function is to calculate the time it takes to finish an embedded SQL query.

```
DELIMITER // 

CREATE FUNCTION
TestIndex (
    P_PARTNAME CHAR(55)
)
RETURNS INTEGER 

BEGIN

    DECLARE
        BEGINTIME TIMESTAMP(3); 
    DECLARE 
        ENDTIME TIMESTAMP(3);
    DECLARE
        DURATION INT;

    SELECT
        CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(3)
    INTO
        BEGINTIME;

    SELECT
        1
    FROM
        PART
    WHERE
        P_NAME = P_PARTNAME;

    SELECT
        CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(3)
    INTO
        ENDTIME;

    SELECT
        TIMESTAMPDIFF(MICROSECOND, BEGINTIME, ENDTIME)
    INTO
        DURATION;

RETURN DURATION;

END //
```

I am using mariaDB, the latest version on Fedora 26 (yes it is on Fedora, can't be newer, haha) - well, I don't think this has anything to do with the version of my DBMS.

While I went through the great solutions from previous posts, I have changed a lot of the original function, and made the best I can to make sure each line is within MySQL's ability (for example, the given example on the textbook uses `PERFORM * FROM`, which is a PostgreSQL special, hence I switched to `SELECT 1 FROM`, according to multiple posts.

I even tried to `RETURN 1` but it still is 1415 error. Did I took any of the syntax rules run? Thanks!!

Comment: You should fix the data types, so you are not returning a timestamp when the function wants to return an int.  And -- as far as I know -- `timestampdiff()` returns an integer, not a `timestamp`.

Comment: `SELECT 1 FROM PART WHERE P_NAME = P_PARTNAME` does not have an `INTO` clause. It's trying to return a result set.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks! I changed the data type of `DURATION` to `INT`, and it still does not work. (I also updated the code in the question)

Comment: @BillKarwin That `SELECT` was a `PERFORM` in the example code in textbook, it was meant to do a `SELECT` query without the need for its result, so to test the query duration.

Comment: There is no such thing in MySQL. The closest is [BENCHMARK()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_benchmark) but that takes an expression, not a full query.

Comment: @BillKarwin Seems a good solution! I just looked it up, and tried to wrap the `SELECT * FROM PART...` into `BENCHMARK()`, but it seemed that *Only scalar expressions can be used. Although the expression can be a subquery, it must return a single column and at most a single row.* I think what needs to be timed is the look up for a complete record, which is a row with multiple columns.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using [sysbench](https://github.com/akopytov/sysbench) for this? Seems like you're reinventing the wheel.

Comment: @BillKarwin I agree with you, it's better to use benchmark tool. I was just trying to do the lab exercise as the textbook does. Now we know the textbook was not written for MySQL, but I think it is possible to find workarounds to finish the function in the question. After all, some later lab exercises depend on this function.

Answer (score 0):

Turn it into a Stored Procedure.  Then you can do `SELECT`, or whatever.

Meanwhile, have an `OUT` parameter that contains the timing result.

The computations can be simplified to skip the declarations and use

```
SET @BEGINTIME := CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6);
...
SET OutResult := TIMESTAMPDIFF(MICROSECOND, @BEGINTIME, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Could you be a little more specific how should I add the `OUT` parameter?